# I want to open default mail client with the pdf attachment

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am developing an web application using .Net2.0. In the application if i click on a button  open a default mail client with PDF should be attached.

I have created the PDF and also tried to open the default mail client.

But the problem is when i checked mail and  it  containing the attachment but when i click on attachment it is again opening with the default mail client.

I need a solution to create a PDF and open the default mail client with same PDF should be attached.

can any body provide the solution to above.

Thanks in advance